# How to execute a method continuosly even if the app is killed or is in background

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager

I want to continuosly execute a method even if the app is not in foreground. For this I have used WorkManager. But problem with this is minimum time delay is 15min, and we cannot reduce this value. Below is the code.

```
final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest
            = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);

public class MyWorker extends Worker {

public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
   
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    //Do work
    return Result.success();
}}
```

How  can I achieve this ? Which is the best approach for this ?

Comment: Well you can see if `repeating alarm` solves your problem. official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Answer (score 0):

For intervals as short as this (10 secs) `WorkManager` or `AlarmManager` are not suitable. Use [Java executors](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do work
    }
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Don't forget to shutdown the executor when you're done with it:

```
executor.shutdown()
```

Comment: Do I need to write this in a service ? I need to run this even if the app is killed from background.

Comment: Service seems a reasonable place to put this, yeah. Note that executors use thread pools, hence you should keep the app process running for the threads to work.